# Are Laws crafted around personal/individual beliefs ethical?

Tags: ethics, society, philosophy-of-law, sociology

For instance.

Gender Identity is defined as what a person believes they are.

Gender Roles is defined as what society constitutes as being a specific gender.

With the latest boom in Gender Identity laws it has made me think of how ethical these types of laws are? If Gender Roles are defined by the collective thought of the society then what right does an individual have to force a person to bend to their notion of gender? The question being are these laws ethical that subvert the will of the majority to please the individual thus mandating kindness in exchange for values and beliefs?

Link to example law - http://www.parl.ca/DocumentViewer/en/42-1/bill/C-16/royal-assent
And the politics Exchange answer regarding the law - https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/20116/14452 which points out that blatant discrimination is not just the only issue

I've edited the title from being about gender identity because I believe this is a general thought and not based around any one type so though the question remains primarily about Gender Identity it can be hosted to a number of things. If a law were crafted that made misrepresenting someones religion illegal this would also fall into this category.

I am okay with any evaluation of the field, but would be interested in Kierkegaard or Nietzsche-in perspective

Comment: There may be hundreds of positions on that matter out there. It would be helpful to narrow the question down to a specifical philosophical network. As it stands, it is too broad to answer objectively.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking I would be fine with multiple answers from different viewpoints. I think it's rare for such a thought to have only one answer.

Comment: @jobermark that is the notion of Gender-Roles which constitute what a society identifies behaviors as. These are subverted by such laws forcing you the majority to subvert their own thought in favor of individualism. This can without a doubt cause discontent and anxiety in the masses can it not?

Comment: @jobermark One this is not about Gender Identity specifically. Two Gay marriage or homosexuality in general has nothing to do with the concept of Gender Identity. Change can occur overtime and that is fine, laws enacted forcing change and taking a concept from the Macro level and turning it micro is another and deserves debating. I am not debating public acceptance I am asking about ethics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61330/discussion-between-scfi-and-jobermark).

Comment: Sorry, I do not follow on "If Gender Roles are defined by the collective thought of the society then what right does an individual have to force a person to bend to their notion of gender?" The linked thread is about passing a law, which is a collective action by society expressing its "collective thought". So this is not about *individuals* forcing anything, but rather about *society* redefining its notion of gender and then forcing everyone to conform to the new one.

Comment: @Conifold This would be true in a republic but Democracy are led through representatives with their own goals and ambitions as such it is not a society changing it is a person changing society. It is the electorates fault at the root but this subversion of societal concepts is the action of an individual. I will put it this way, if the Representative is corrupt would you say the people that elected him are corrupt

Comment: I do not see what difference corruption makes. Tolerating it or not, accepting its consequences or not are choices of the society, which it can collectively alter (and in a democracy that is simpler and less dangerous). Going with the flow is also its choice. How can an "individual" do much of anything here without being socially enabled at every turn? If there is a passive majority silently acquiescing to new gender rules that *is* society changing. And if not, "corrupt" representatives will be removed and laws revised.

Comment: @Conifold Corruption was just an example of the representatives not being indicative of the whole of society. Not calling the people that passed the law corrupt. If I am understanding your argument because the majority voted for the law makers and are not protesting in the streets means that society is accepting and integrating it? I honestly cannot argue with that, but that is not what the question is about. The question is about the ethical nature of the law mandating that personal beliefs trump societal expectations. If you have any recommendation for an edit please let me know.

Comment: To me the premise of the question (that "individuals" are responsible) is very questionable. You also seem to treat individual beliefs and societal expectations as if the latter were set in stone and insulated from the former. But the latter merely sum total the former and laws are vehicles for changing both. So the question I see is when it is ethical for a *society* to prescribe how its members should behave concerning the gender of others (or other characteristics), and whether the recent laws pass the ethical muster  (minus the "individuals" and malleable "societal expectations").

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61334/discussion-between-scfi-and-conifold).

Answer (score 1):

Gender 'roles' in the sense you are defining them exist only because gender roles in a more [legitimate sociological definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_role) have always existed.  We label men and women and become attached to those labels, because we have traditionally expected very different things from them.  When we had compulsory conscription and the working women always got fired first, because they always had a fallback role, this *really, really mattered*.  It no longer does.

Since the male role has been extended to everyone now -- women can be soldiers, etc. we no longer have such expectations.  So it is not longer really important how we are labeled by the culture.

If it happens to be extremely important to some individuals, there is no longer a pressing public interest in insisting on the label, because it is not the basis for any important public expectations, like going to war, or raising children.  It is not clear that this is going to be the case indefinitely, but right now, gender roles mean almost nothing.  The expectations of men and women are the same.

Social norms shift.  There is not currently a real consensus on what proper gender roles are in our society, so attempts by individuals to press their own chosen definitions of them are out of line with the majority position -- which is that there is not a consensus.  When there is not a consensus, choosing to enforce traditional roles because they are traditional is not effecting the will of the majority.  It is distorting perception.

In the U.S. at least, when there is no pressing public reason to resist internal promptings, and those are genuine, we defend them.  The combination of the 1st amendment and the existence of Pennsylvania means that we have forever agreed to not infringe on religion, and one of those religions, from very early on, has been [Quakerism](https://www.google.com/search?q=Quakerism&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS751US751&oq=Quakerism&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1792j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), which *has no credal elements* and simply acknowledges "leadings of conscience."

There are standards for what the court will take seriously, but for instance [vegans do not have to dissect frogs in public schools](http://www.onegreenplanet.org/animalsandnature/how-you-can-get-dissection-alternatives-available-at-your-school/).  This is not a religious idea, but it is seen as an infringement of religion to force someone to violate it.  A good part of the LGBT community holds the identification of one's own gender identity to be the same kind of insistence, and a majority of the public in general does not report strongly disagreeing, [when actually asked](http://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2016/10/03/americans-are-divided-over-which-public-bathrooms-transgender-people-should-use/).

History is not an ethical argument, but it has come to have an ethical stance behind it.  We have decided to defend quirky individuals when they go well out of their way to hold strongly onto a belief, they are not alone in that belief, and they appear to be genuine in their attachment to it.

---

Both of the authors you would like answers from the positions of had immense disdain for majority opinions as a way of deciding things.  Neither of them approved of majority rule to begin with.  Nietzsche considered it a disease of the herd mentality, and Kierkegaard considered democratic opinion the worst form of tyranny.

So the government enforcement of majority norms would disgust them both.

Comment: That's not what the question is about. And your definition would be equivalent of saying because a society is composed of individuals and individuals may have conflicting thoughts that no form of societal ethics exist

Comment: No.  That is a complete misunderstanding.  There are things we have consensus on.  This is just not one of them.  By what logic do you convert what I said into what you claim I said?  There isn't any...  If no social norms existed, they could not shift!!

Comment: "There is not currently a real consensus"  So it's a meaningless term as it has no hard definition? "attempt to enforce are out of line with the majority position" And society does not acknowledge them. As it is a societal concept it is as akin to saying that it does not exist? I fail to see where I am misrepresenting. Also Kierkegaard believed in societal ethics just not democratic christianity that God was the sole metaethic/Religous ruler and that those metaethics trumped societal ethics on the road to being a knight of faith

Comment: No, it is in the state of changing and does not have a majority position.  We are, as a society re-evaluating gender, and a minority don't approve of the fact that means things are ambiguous.

Comment: I didn't say otherwise.  But government enforcement of majority norms, just because they were majority norms, and not because they were based in something deeper would in fact still disgust him.  You are making up a lot I never said.

Comment: I quite literally quoted you and that statement is different then what is in the answer. For the life of me I cannot piece together. What do you think Gender Roles denote in the context of a society. Though I think we should take this back to chat.

Comment: "There is currently not bus" does not mean "'Bus' is a meaningless word that has no hard definition".  To make such a deduction would be an obvious indication that the listener was not well-intended.  I take it that you are not well-intended toward attempting to actually read what I am saying.  Your previous behavior in chat indicates the same.

Comment: I have detailed what I believe you are saying however claiming that an old concept like Gender Role  is not currently  defined is bias and asinine as we have had established Genders in society for generations and what it means to be those has changed over that time. You seem dedicated to obfuscating your point. Claiming there is no current concept of Gender-Role would be to say that society is gender confused and probably suffering from massive anxiety which is quite a big jump that would require sources.

Comment: Also thinking about Kierkegaard would turn to Gods judgement to answer this and would probably be completely opposed due to the concept of the problem not so much the implications of the decision as God derives ultimate ethics in his type of philosophy

Comment: I am not going to put up with your attitude.  You need to argue fairly or leave.

Comment: I am not trying to be hostile but asking for sources and pointing out flaws in thinking that are repeated over and over again is not trying to constitute an attitude. You are making declarations denouncing the current observable world and history while not providing anything to back up these notions.

Comment: I have expressed what I mean at some length.  I do not expect more flack.  if you don't like the answer just ignore it.

Comment: Calling me asinine is being hostile, whether or not you are trying.

Comment: I think we're done here. I was calling the point asinine as far as I can see it it is not fully fleshed out and is more an aesthetic appeal that has been repeated many times. I have a feeling that you are personally invested in this issue and I meean no insult to you, but I don't think we will agree

Comment: I said I was done here a while ago, yet, you kept pressing the issue.  Third way you are just being rude.  When I said 'I am done here', your answer was 'I am SCFi'.  *That* is more asinine than anything you have so labeled.

Comment: Rued? you spend 7 Paragraphs arguing about your perspective on gender roles and give a quick plip of the actual answer to the question with almost no detail or reasoning of note. The answer is more vested in the a detail of the question and is ignorant of the question itself.

Comment: Insults and calumny are not arguments.  Insisting on redefining terms that have real definitions is not philosophy.  You have no interest in listening, and BTW *spelling flame* totally paints you as a troll.